# Python Multithread two lines of code

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, process

My script finds data from two websites and compares them.

It takes about 4 seconds to do them.

Is there anyway to make it faster.

I have tried multi threading but they don't work because one uses requests and other uses another module to get the data. So i can't pass arguments in a requests function.

What I am trying to achieve is

```
requests.get(firsturl)
apicall(secondurl)
```

How can these lines run parallel so it becomes faster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import concurrent.futures

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:
    first = pool.submit(requests.get, firsturl)
    second = pool.submit(apicall, secondurl)
```

Then you can use first.result() and second.result().  The thread pool will wait for both to finish before exiting the `with` block.

Comment: error    <bound method Future.result of <Future at 0x41a78b0 state=finished raised TypeError>>

Comment: first = pool.submit(k.query_public('Ticker'))
 **second = pool.submit(requests.get('https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/trade))**

Comment: Well, you are doing `pool.submit(requests.get(url))` when I told you to do `pool.submit(requests.get, url)`.

Comment: Woah, I thought argument must be passed in requests. Your answer worked. I don't understand it, can you please give a source so i can understand ?

Comment: The time is now 1.8 instead of 4. Thank you very much!